# Why is custom validation pipe injectable in Nest.js?

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typescript-decorator

The documentation suggests to make custom validation pipes `@Injectable` - https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#object-schema-validation.

However in the documentation it is not injected and can work even without the `@Injectable` decorator.

Custom validation pipe:

```
class SchemaValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  #schema;

  constructor(schema: ISchema) {
    this.#schema = schema;
  }

  transform(value: any) {
    try {
      return this.#schema.parse(value);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new SchemaValidationError();
    }
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
import SchemaValidationPipe from 'src/lib/schema/schema-validation-pipe';

...

@Controller()
class CarsController {
  @Post()
  @UsePipes(new SchemaValidationPipe(carSchema))
  submit(@Body() carDto: any) {
    console.log(carDto);
  }
}
```

The example above works fine (notice that `SchemaValidationPipe` is not injectable).

But at the same time I would actually want my validation pipe to be injectable.
I would put `@Injectable` decorator and do something like this:

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'schema_validation_pipe',
      useClass: SchemaValidationPipe,
    },
  ],
  exports: ['schema_validation_pipe'],
})
export class SchemaModule {}
```

```
@Controller()
class CarsController {
  constructor(
    @Inject('schema_validation_pipe')
    private readonly SchemaValidationPipe,
  ) {}

  @Post()
  @UsePipes(new this.SchemaValidationPipe(carSchema))
  submitReport(@Body() carDto: any) {
    console.log(cartDto);
  }
}
```

but obviously it doesn't work as I can't access `this` inside of the `@UsePipes` definition.

So how can I inject my custom validation pipe to use it in `@UsePipes`?
And what is the point of making it `@injectable` in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where you may want Nest to create the pipe for you, so you'd add `@Injectable()` to the pipe and pass `@UsePipes(PipeClassReference)` and Nest will do the injections for you. In your case, it doesn't look necessary, so you don't need to worry about making it a provider.

---

Your injections in your example doesn't make sense either, Nest will call `new` but have nothing to pass to your pipe, then you're trying to `new` it again, which is rather nonsensical